# Правильное вычисление размера файла

Tags: php, include, require

Файл_А включает в себя (include/require) файл_Б, а тот включает в себя файл_В

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно определить размер файла_Б с файлом_В (получается сумму размеров) находясь в файле_А? Ведь файл_А знает только о файле_Б при вычислении размера.

Comment: Хм. при такой постановке вопроса думаю стоит смотреть в сторону [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php) + [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: @MaximTimakov, спасибо за ответ. Скажите, а такой подход сильно нагружает сервер? Ведь получается вся страница вместе с включениями сохраняется в память. Просто я на бесплатном хостинге, а там наверняка чуть что сразу выкинут

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, страница и без них сначала идет в память.

Comment: Для начала неплохо бы объяснить, для чего в принципе понадобилось такое извращение

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну например в идее MVC, файл контроллера подключает вид, или контроллер подключает модель. Мне нужно вывести информацию об изменении страницы (на основе изменения размера или просто дату модификации), но страница получается состоит из трёх компонентов и изменение каждого должно учитываться. Если есть способ получше, подскажите

Comment: Ничего не понял. С какой стати изменение файла модели имеет хоть какое-то отношение к изменению какой-то страницы? Можно без "ну например", а написать какое конкретно извращенное понимание базовых принципов привело к этому кривому вопросу?

Comment: @Ипатьев, в этом "ну например" есть как раз ситуация которая может привести к этому вопросу. Тут стоит понять не именно самой модели, хотя и это тоже, тут несколько шире - по направлению модели, то есть сама база данных и сам php-файл модели

Comment: Понятно. Изобретай дальше, кулибин.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну я в принципе догадался уже что Вам нечего добавить